# Recreating many dynamic controls in ASP NET (individually actions)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I have problem with ASP.NET and dynamic controls. I have three ASCX. One of them creates two textboxes and some labels. The second containing control created if first ASCX (two textboxes and some labels). In addiction, second control also have link button named “Add Next” which on click event adding another control (two textboxes and some labels). The third ASCX control contains many the second ASCX (amount depend on SQL result). I made simple image to clarify:

[image]

The orange box contains many controls. The red box adding many black boxes on click “ADD NEXT”.

For now I use session variable to save state during recreate. For one “red box” it is working, but if I add more “red boxes”, clicking every “ADD NEXT” adding new control with textboxes and labels to every “red box” instead of in this where was clicked button “ADD NEXT”. I suppose why it is happening. Because every “red box” refers to the same Session variable, but I don’t know how to fix it. I was trying during OnClick event passing unique ID and setting this ID as session variable name, but it wasn’t working as I expected. 
Could you tell me, how to manage it? How looks the best way to recreate controls, how I can manage controls individually? If something is not clear, I will clarify. Always I was finding answers in stackoverflow, but this problem has outgrow me. 
Best wishes.
(Sorry for my English, it doesn’t my native language)

My code.

Code for creating textboxes and some labels (Calculator.cs):

```
public string FLong
{
    get
    {
        object o = ViewState["FLong"];
        if (o == null)
            return String.Empty;
        return (string)o;
    }
    set { ViewState["FLong"] = value; }
}

public string FWide
{
    get
    {
        object o = ViewState["FWide"];
        if (o == null)
            return String.Empty;
        return (string)o;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["FWide"] = value;

    }
}
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    CreateControlHierarchy();
    ClearChildViewState();
}

protected virtual void CreateControlHierarchy()
{

    Literal row = new Literal();
    row.Text = "<div class='row surface'>";
    Controls.Add(row);
    //Add new TextBox;

    Literal col = new Literal();
    col.Text = "<div class='col-xs-4'>";
    Controls.Add(col);

    TextBox fLong = new TextBox();
    fLong.ID = "fLong";
    fLong.CssClass = "form-control";

    //fLong.TextChanged += new EventHandler(Calculate_TextChanged);
    //fLong.AutoPostBack = true;
    fLong.Text = FLong;
    Controls.Add(fLong);

    Literal textLong = new Literal();
    textLong.Text = "<span>ft. long x</span>";
    Controls.Add(textLong);

    RegularExpressionValidator flongValidate = new RegularExpressionValidator();
    flongValidate.ControlToValidate = "fLong";
    flongValidate.ErrorMessage = "Only Numbers allowed";
    flongValidate.ValidationExpression = @"\d+";
    flongValidate.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    flongValidate.Attributes["style"] = "display:block";
    Controls.Add(flongValidate);



    Literal colEnd = new Literal();
    colEnd.Text = "</div>";
    Controls.Add(colEnd);
    //Add new Textbox

    Literal col2 = new Literal();
    col2.Text = "<div class='col-xs-4'>";
    Controls.Add(col2);

    TextBox fWide = new TextBox();
    fWide.ID = "fWide";
    fWide.CssClass = "form-control";


    fWide.Text = FWide;
    Controls.Add(fWide);

    Literal textWide = new Literal();
    textWide.Text = "<span>ft. wide</span>";
    Controls.Add(textWide);

    RegularExpressionValidator fwideValidate = new RegularExpressionValidator();
    fwideValidate.ControlToValidate = "fWide";
    fwideValidate.ErrorMessage = "Only Numbers allowed";
    fwideValidate.ValidationExpression = @"\d+";
    fwideValidate.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    fwideValidate.Attributes["style"] = "display:block";
    Controls.Add(fwideValidate);



    Literal col2End = new Literal();
    col2End.Text = "</div>";
    Controls.Add(col2End);


    Literal rowEnd = new Literal();
    rowEnd.Text = "</div>";
    Controls.Add(rowEnd);

}
```

Code handling recreating (SurfaceCalculator.cs):

```
private int DefaultAmountControls = 1;
private string surfaceID;

public string SurfaceID
{
    get { return surfaceID; }
    set { surfaceID = value; }
}

public int Visibility
{
    get
    {
        //store the object in session if not already stored
        if (Session[surfaceID] == null)
            Session[surfaceID] = DefaultAmountControls;

        //return the object from session
        return (int)Session[surfaceID];
    }
    set
    {
        if (value <= 5)
            Session[surfaceID] = value;
        else
            Session[surfaceID] = 5;
    }
}

protected void addSurface_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton b = (LinkButton)sender;
    surfaceID = b.CommandArgument;
    Visibility += 1;
}
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{

    LinkButton addSurface = new LinkButton();
    addSurface.Text = "+ Add surface";
    addSurface.CommandArgument = surfaceID;
    addSurface.Click += new EventHandler(addSurface_Click);
    base.OnInit(e);
    List<Calculator> c = Surface.Controls.OfType<Calculator>().ToList();
    for (int i = 1; i <= Visibility; i++)
    {
        c.ElementAt(i - 1).Visible = true;
    }
    if (Visibility >= 5)
    {
        addSurface.Enabled = false;
    }

    Controls.Add(addSurface);

}
```

Code to adding many controls depending on SQL result

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    var listOfProjects = //GETTING FROM SQL
    if(listOfProjects != null)
    {
        foreach (var proj in listOfProjects)
        {
            Panel placeHolder = new Panel();
            placeHolder.CssClass = "surface";
            placeHolder.ID = "placeHolder" + proj.DocumentID;
            surfacesContainer.Controls.Add(placeHolder);

            SurfaceCalculator newElement = (SurfaceCalculator)LoadControl("~/PATH_TO/CONTROL.ascx");

            newElement.ID = "surfaceCalculator" + proj.DocumentID;

            newElement.SurfaceID = newElement.ID;
            placeHolder.Controls.Add(newElement);

        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code samples? Looks like you will need to recreate controls on Postback.

Comment: @SachinNambiarNalavattanon I added my source code.

Comment: Can you add code for the form load event too?

Comment: Have a look at using a bound Repeater to instantiate your child controls.

Comment: @SachinNambiarNalavattanon In page load event for now I have not any code.

Comment: @Reddog I didn't think about that,  I will try.